# Use WPF in combination with hardware rendering is - laggy

Tags: c#, wpf, rendering, lag, hardware-acceleration

I have just created a new WPF project. When I run the solution the whole window and mouse is starting to lag and that without having written a line of source code.
Everything is fine when I use the RenderOptions "RenderMode.SoftwareOnly".
Iam using nvidia 2080 series as Hardware and wondering why I have that kind of trouble.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a kind of drivers issue. Similar problems are quite rare (it may occur even on a specific display) but I am afraid I have not saw any solution so far. The SoftwareOnly mode is the only generic solution suggested by MS.